# Trying to populate ListView from MS Access database

Tags: c#, listview, oledb

I am trying to create a method that returns all the data of a column so that data can be used on a listview to populate it.

```
    public static Array populatelistview()
{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM trainlines_"; 
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection); 
    command.Connection = myConnection;

    DataSet trainlinedata = new DataSet();
    trainlinedata.Clear();
    OleDbDataAdapter datareader = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    datareader.Fill(trainlinedata);
    myConnection.Close();
    return trainlinedata;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am getting an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.Array' for the last line i.e. return trainlinedata;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `DataSet` Type not `Array`.Because `trainlinedata` is declare as `DataSet`

```
public static DataSet populatelistview()
{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM trainlines_"; 
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection); 
    command.Connection = myConnection; 
    DataSet trainlinedata = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter datareader = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    datareader.Fill(trainlinedata);
    myConnection.Close();
    return trainlinedata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From question it appears you able to fetch data from relevant source. I think all you need is to bind this result array to Listview control. Something like below

```
ListView1.DataSource = trainlinedata.Tables["yourTableName"];
ListView1.DataBind();
```